# Stop script till I press enter

Tags: shell-script, startup

I have a startup script that opens some programs in each workspace. I want to do some things in the first workspace before it continues opening the programs in the next workspaces. How can I prompt to continue? I've tried using `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"read -s -p 'Press enter to continue...'\""` but it doesn't stop, the script continues executing even though I haven't used `&` to move the process to background.

```
wmctrl -n 2
sleep 2
wmctrl -s 0
sleep 1
if command -v "firefox" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    firefox  &
fi
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"read -n1 -sp 'Press enter to continue...'\""
# sleep 30
wmctrl -s 1
sleep 1
if command -v "firefox" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    firefox --new-window &
fi
```

Comment: Why not make that prompt in the terminal that is already running that script? Or do you want a dialog box of some sort to appear anywhere?

Comment: It doesn't appear when the script is executed as a startup application so I have to find an alternative.

Comment: Is your staturtup script running as your user? because if it's running as root you have no control over it whatsoever while running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea about the `gnome-terminal`, but if I start my `xfce4-terminal` from an already running terminal, it immediately forks itself into a standalone process, such that control can be returned to the calling shell, i.e. the previous shell will accept new commands while the new one is running as well.

I believe the `gnome-terminal` behaves the same way, which is why your script doesn't seem to stop-and-wait.

You could use the standard `xterm` instead, which does not fork itself and thus blocks the calling script. It doesn't look as pretty, but it'll do as a simple block-alert.

You may also have a look at `gxmessage`, `xmessage` or `zenity`.

Comment: It works perfectly with `xterm -e "bash -c \"read -n1 -sp 'Press enter to continue...'\""`. I tried the rest of options and they all work too. You could add the command to complete the answer.
```if command -v "zenity" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    zenity --question --text "Open workspaces"
    if [ $? = 1 ]; then
        exit
    fi
else
    echo "Install zenity"
fi
```